# Sinon stub not allowing for test coverage on actual function

Tags: node.js, typescript, unit-testing, sinon

Here is the function under test:

```
export const callStoredProcedure = async (procedureName, procedureArgs)
 => {
  let resultSet: any;
  try {
    await knexClient.transaction(async trx => {
      await trx.raw(`CALL ${procedureName}(${procedureArgs});`).then(result => {
        if (result[0] && result[0][0]) {
          resultSet = JSON.stringify(result[0][0]);
        }
      });
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
  return resultSet;
};
```

And here I'm mocking the knexClient in a beforeEach block:

```
 let knexClientMock;
  beforeEach(() => {
    // Stub Data source clients
    const rawStub = sinon.stub().resolves([{ affectiveRows: 0, insertId: 0 }]);
    knexClientMock = sinon.stub(knexClient, 'transaction').callsFake(
      async (): Promise<any> => {
        return {
          raw: rawStub,
        };
      },
    );
  });
```

However, when I run my tests the if statement `if (result[0] && result[0][0])` never runs and Jest coverage shows everything is uncovered from the `raw` statement down to the `catch`.

The mocking seems to be working correctly in that it uses the mock `knexClient.transaction`, but it leaves the rest of the lines uncovered. I think I just want to mock the `raw` function with a mock promise result and allow the `.then` function to run.

How can I mock the `knexClient.transaction.raw` function only and allow the rest of the code to have test coverage?

Comment: What happens when you mark your transaction stub as async? Right now the callback given to transaction is async in the code, but sync in your mock. Probably what is happening in your tests is that your catch handler is logging a TypeError due to no property `then` existing on the return object.

Comment: Nice catch, but it doesn't seem to fix the issue. I marked `sinon.stub(knexClient, 'tranaction') as async but still having the same issue. Btw, there are no errors being thrown/caught. I will edit the original post with the new code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that your test stubs do not correctly mock the objects being used:

The "transaction" method in your code takes a single argument (a callback function) and *invokes this callback*, passing it a transaction executor that has an asynchronous "raw" method.

Your test stubs make the "transaction" method *return* an object that has an async raw method.

When writing unit tests for your code, it is very important to understand how your code works, first. Otherwise it is extremely easy to write meaningless tests that won't protect against introducing bugs.